# Oracle cloud Setting up VM

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have created a new virtual server instance with an Image name is Canonical Ubuntu and for the network I chose to create a new virtual cloud network with a new public subnet. And for SSH key I generated a public key and uploaded it.

When I try connection command to the server

ssh [Username] [publicIP ad] It works

But I try using the the command

Sftp -i [location of the public key] [username]@[ip]

I get: [Permission denied(public key)]

The file path is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using the private key from your client, instead of the public key?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup sftp and configure. You may refer to https://linuxhint.com/setup-sftp-server-ubuntu/